# Match any except list of values - oracle regex

Tags: regex, oracle

I need an Oracle regex that will match a file-name in the format `ABCD_EFG_YYYYMMDD_HH(24)MISS.csv`, *except* if the time-part is one of three specific values: `110000`, `140000`, or `180000`.

So, for example, it will match the file-name `ABC_DEF_20120925_110001.csv`, but not the file-name `ABCD_EFG_20120925_110000.csv` is not.

The following non-Oracle regex works:

```
^ABCD_EFG_[0-9]*_(?!110000|140000|180000)[0-9]*\.csv$
```

but I don't know how to write it as an Oracle regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support lookahead assertions, so you'll have to spell out all the valid matches:

```
^ABCD_EFG_[0-9]*_([02-9]|1[0235679]|1[148]0{0,3}[1-9])[0-9]*\.csv$
```

should work (assuming that the time part is always 6 digits long).

**Explanation:**

```
ABCD_EFG_    # Match ABCD_EFG_
[0-9]*_      # Match first number (date part) and _
(            # Match a number that starts with
 [02-9]      # 0 or 2-9
|            # or
 1[0235679]  # 1, followed by 2,3,5,6,7, or 9
|            # or
 1[148]      # 11, 14, or 18
 0{0,3}      # followed by up to three zeroes
 [1-9]       # but then one digit 1-9
)            # End of alternation
[0-9]*       # Fill the rest with any digits
\.csv        # Match .csv (mind the backslash!)
```